# Android IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm checking if the in app purchase has been made or not. If the purchase was made, I want to open ActivityB, if it was not done, I want to Apiro InAppBillingActivity. But when I call the method `Controlla_record_per_acquisto ()`, nothing happens. I do not understand where is the problem. Thank you for your help

In onCreate()

```
 String base64EncodedPublicKey =".........."; 
     m1Helper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), base64EncodedPublicKey);

        m1Helper.enableDebugLogging(true);

        m1Helper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (m1Helper == null) return;
                List<String> st = new ArrayList<String>();
                st.add(ITEM_SKU);     
                QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = null;
                m1Helper.queryInventoryAsync(true,st, mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });
```

and the Method:

```
private void Controlla_record_per_acquisto(){
     SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
    String controllo = "SELECT COUNT(_id) FROM table";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(controllo, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        int numero_id = c.getInt(0);            

    if(numero_id >=1){                      

        IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

                if (m1Helper == null) return;

                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    return;
                }

                if(inventory.hasPurchase(ITEM_SKU)) {
                     Intent intent = null;
                     intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class); 
                     startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };

    }else   {       
        Intent intent = null;
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InAppBillingActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot simply call "your method", because thats not the way inappbilling works.

To activate your inappbilling process and listeners you have to call:

m1Helper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
                   mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");

Look at this:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Comment: In fact, I have created the activity InAppBillingActivity from that tutorial and it works well. My question is another, I have to check from another Activity if the purchase has been made or not.

Comment: Add logcat flags in every if statement in your onqueryinventoryfinished and see what part is called.